# Output a list of JSON data to a JSON array and write them to file

Tags: python, json

I have a list with some data, already serialised in JSON:

```
>>> import json
>>> a = []
>>> a.append(json.dumps({"key1":"value1"}))
>>> a.append(json.dumps({"key2":"value2"}))
>>> a
['{"key1": "value1"}', '{"key2": "value2"}']
```

How can I convert this list into a JSON array and output them in a file in the format:

```
[  
   {
      "key1": "value1"
   },
   {
      "key2": "value2"
   }
]
```

The following won't work as each list element is already serialised in JSON.

```
with open('test_output.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dumps(a, outfile)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn a list of json strings into a list of json objects, you have a few options for applying `json.loads` to each element in the array. Exhibit A, list comprehension:

```
parsed_data = [json.loads(s) for s in a]
```

Exhibit B, [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#map):

```
parsed_data = map(json.loads, a)
```

Or, to create a `list` using `map`:

```
parsed_data = list(map(json.loads, a))
```

EDIT: to output this new data structure into the desired format, you can do:

```
with open('output.json', 'w') as fs:
    json.dump(parsed_data, fs, indent=4)
```

Comment: I've provided a minimal example. As I mentioned, the data is already in JSON format so your solution won't work.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case, you'll need to apply `json.loads` to each element. I'll update my response accordingly.

Comment: And how should I write `parsed_data` to the output file?

Comment: See EDIT. I'd also look over the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/json.html#json.dump) for `json.dump` to familiarize yourself with all the different options.

Comment: Thanks. Edit the code in order to include `'w'` in `open()` function: with `open('output.json', 'w') as fs:`